# Qt, How can I sort QTableWidget column if the cells are widgets

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a `QTableWidget`, some columns are filled with text, some with numbers, these columns are fine to sort. But I also have a column with custom widgets, how should I enable sorting for these?

My first thought was of course to overload the `'<'` method on the `QTableWidgetItem`, but there are no `QTableWidgetItem`. So what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: you could provide a [mcve] of your problem, for example the custom widget, regarding which parameter you want to order, etc.

Comment: I would argue that in this case there is not much more info to add from an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTableWidget` is not ideal for this case, consider using `QTableView`. Anyway, I will show you how to sort a `QProgressBar` widget in a `QTableWidget`.

As you already said, you can overload the `<() operator` for this case. Let's say you have a `QProgressBar` in column number 4. You have to overload the `<()` operator.

You have to subclass `QProgressBar` and `QTableWidgetItem`.

```
class CustomTableWidgetItem : public QProgressBar, public QTableWidgetItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomTableWidgetItem( QWidget* parent ) : QProgressBar( parent )
    {
    }

    CustomTableWidgetItem(const QString txt = QString("0"))
        :QTableWidgetItem(txt)
    {
    }

    bool operator <(const QTableWidgetItem& other) const
    {
         if(other.column() == 0 /* numeric cell */) {
             return QTableWidgetItem::text().toInt() < other.text().toInt();
         }
         else if(other.column() == 4 /* progress bar */) {
            const QProgressBar *p = dynamic_cast<const QProgressBar *>(&other);
            if(p != 0) {
                if(this->value() < p->value())
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

And then you can insert your QProgressBar like this in cell number 4.

Insert `QProgressBar` like this

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
CustomTableWidgetItem *pgbar = new CustomTableWidgetItem(this);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 4, pgbar);
ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 4, pgbar);
```

Let's say you want to have simple text at cell 1 use `QTableWidgetItem`.

```
ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Hello"));
```

If you want to sort numbers as well, for example in cell 0 use CustomTableWidgetItem, since we have implemented an if-statement as you can see above for sorting numbers and progressbar.

```
ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 0, new CustomTableWidgetItem(QString::number(ui->tableWidget->rowCount())));
```

You can use this approach with other widgets as well, just subclass the correct widget, but in general it's better to use QTableView (MVC approach).

Here is a screenshot with `QTableWidget` and `QProgressBar` sorting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My custom widget is actually a specialization of the QProgressBar, so this example is perfect. I never considered inheriting the QTableWidgetItem class though. Will try this out.

Comment: Actually I can't make this work. The operator is never getting called.
If I'm not able to fix it, I'll create an example case (slightly different from yours).

Comment: I added a follow up with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416179/qt-inherit-from-qtablewidgetitem-to-widget-and-overide-operator