# Sorting using QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget.
I have a problem with sorting files and folders.I have tried out the following meethods:

```
ui.table->horizontalHeader()->sortIndicatorOrder();
ui.table->sortItems(columnNumber, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

Suppose my first column consists of files and folders.How do I ensure that, folders always remain on top and files remain after the folders?

Do I need to implement some kind of boolean operator " < " for QTableWidget class.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using QTableWidget for files and folders, because the number of files and folders is not known. QTableWidget's performance with a huge number of items is bad.

You should learn how to do [Model/View programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html), and in the link there's an example on how to deal with files.

With model view, you have a view that takes information from a model. The model can be (almost) arbitrarily huge, and the view doesn't care because it only loads what it's viewing. This is unlike QTableWidget which loads everything all the time, and causes performance hick-ups.

Now regarding your question about sorting, you should use [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html), which you set as a model for your view, and you set inside `QSortFilterProxyModel` a source model. The proxy works as a middle-man between your view and the model, and can sort and filter the information before passing it. That's the right way of sorting tables in Qt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Performance is really not a problem. Please explain the method to do that in QTableWidget

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast, Sorry. I don't do things the wrong way. Maybe someone else can help you in doing it the wrong way. You can probably look at this as an opportunity for you to learn how to do it right.

Comment: Both answers are valuable. This one is more correct regarding architecture and development in Qt, user3606329's answer  is more ad-hoc to quick fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can overload `<()` operator and implement a sorting logic.

```
class CustomTableWidgetItem : public QTableWidgetItem
{

public:

    CustomTableWidgetItem(const QString txt = QString("0")) 
    :QTableWidgetItem(txt)
    {
        setTextAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter ); /* center the text */
    }

    bool operator <(const QTableWidgetItem& other) const
    {
        /* Implement logic here */
        /* e.g if(column == file) return true; */
        /* else return false; */
    }
};
```

Then use `new CustomTableWidgetItem` instead of `new QTableWidgetItem`. Read my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390129/qt-how-can-i-sort-qtablewidget-column-if-the-cells-are-widgets/49393715#49393715) to see how it's done on a widget.

**Performance note:** If you have many rows use the model view approach, if you just deal with a couple of rows QTableWidget should be fine. If you notice the sorting will take a couple of seconds it's time to switch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Basically, I am a bit confused about the logic,which needs to be implemented.  auto *otheritem = dynamic_cast<const CustomTableWidgetItem*>(&other); Now,I am not sure,how to proceed. Can you tell me the cases,which I need to manage.  Instead of if(colum ==  file), how do you use "other" here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Math_Enthusiast: you need to set an attribute for example with `setData()` to the item. You can't know which row is a folder or file otherwise. Then in `<()` operator read the attribute and return true or false. Or if you have set a folder as icon you can read that with `icon()`.

Comment: Ok,I have a procedure,through which,I can know,if the parameter "other" is file or folder. then for my problem statement, folder should aways remain on top. So,  for example, if I retrieve that, "other" is a file,do I return false, and if "other" is folder,do I return true??

Comment: Math_Enthusiast: You have `QTableWidgetItem::text()` and `other.text()`. Perhaps it works as you said for a random folder sorting. If you want to sort the folder from A-Z, you need to compare both by name and attribute folder.

Comment: I still could not understand clearly mate. Suppose,I have attributes "file" and "folder". So, now you have file, other.file ; folder; other.folder. Like, file will return if given item is a file or not and folder will return if given item is a folder or not. How do I ensure that folders always remain on top? Also,during this process,do I need to add these lines: ui.table->setSortingEnabled( true ) ?? Can you p;lease explain the implementation,if  like I said I have all the 4 parameters(file, other.file, folder, other.folder).

Comment: Math_Enthusiast: You need to set  `setSortingEnable` to `true` then you can sort by clicking the header column. If you want to sort automatically once you have to call `sortByColunmn(int index)`. For insertion you need  to set `setSortingEnable` to `false`. When you clicked the header sorting of further insertions are done automaticaly. No need to cal sortByColumn.

Comment: I wrote two cases. like case1: if (file && other.folder) return false; . Case 2: if(folder && other.file) return true;...Now,the problem is "folders are remaining on top or on bottom".I always want folders to remain on top.Please tell me the lines,which i can modify. Hope you understood my code.

Comment: Math_Enthusiast: Try to edd additionally an else statement with return false/true. If it doesn't work I can later give you an example